# Can I convert a gulp stream into a String?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to apply some tasks in a gulp stream and get the output string. I dont want create a new file.

This is my code:

```
function buildCSS() {

    // READ A FILE AND APPLY SOME TASKS
    var content = gulp.src(__dirname + '/src/styles.less')
        .pipe(g.less());

    if (environment === 'live') {
        content.pipe(g.minifyCss());
    }

    // I NEED RETURN A STRING
    return content;
}

gulp.task('build-html', function() {

  // I SHOULD GET THE CSS TEXT 
  var cssText = buildCSS(); 

  gulp.src(__dirname + '/src/template.html')
        // INSERT THE CSS IN A HTML FILE (REPLACE AS STRING)
        .pipe(g.replace('/*INJECT:CSS*/', cssText))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/dist/'));

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `return` the content from a file in a gulp stream. That's impossible because the stream is asynchronous so the content isn't even available yet when you try `return` it from your function.

You have to listen for the [`"data"` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) in the stream and then perform whatever you want to do in the event handler function:

```
gulp.task('build-html', function(cb) {

  buildCSS().on('data', function(file) {
    var cssText = file.contents.toString();
    gulp.src(__dirname + '/src/template.html')
      .pipe(g.replace('/*INJECT:CSS*/', cssText))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/dist/'))
      .on('end', cb);
  });

});
```